# Bounty was not awarded and the answer was accepted

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

A bounty of 250 rep was not awarded.

I answered  the question and the answer was accepted as the correct answer several days before the bounty expired, the answer had 3 up-votes and was the only answer.

I went through three iterations as the question changed and I spent a reasonable amount of time on the answer, it was complete code with log output and well commented.

The SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28509594/451475).

What am I missing?

Here is the text from the help system:
"If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration."

That paragraph has no mention about when the answer was started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28509594/revisions) shows:

> Bounty Ended with no winning answer by Community♦

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/202832) about the bounty system lists the following requirement for a bounty to be automatically awarded:

> The answer *must* have been given after the bounty was started

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28511185/1234256) was posted on the 14th. You started your bounty on the 16th.

Comment: Scenario: A question is asked. An answer is provided. The questions is modified and the answer is extended. Then a bounty is offered. The question is modified again and the answer is again estended. The question is accepted and up-voted three times. The bounty is not awarded by the OP and expires. The bounty is not automatically awarded. It seems to me that just because I started helping the OP before the bounty was created I am not eligible to receive it? That seems to wrong because it penalizes me for my initial help.

Comment: So, if I had deleted my initial answer along with the comments relevant to the question and started a new answer I would have been awarded the bounty? If so that is a rather strange bounty design.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is correct. The OP had the responsibility to award the bounty, but didn't. Bounties are generally started because there are no good answers. The system makes the assumption that existing answers won't be drastically improved. But yes, if you deleted your answer and reposted it after the bounty started, you would've received it. Not what you wanted to hear, I'm sure.

Comment: Yeah! From the OP's last comment he was unhappy that his question had been down-voted twice. The final edit to the answer was substantial and was the reason the answer was accepted was made **after** the bounty was started.

Comment: I agree that you should've gotten the bounty. If you think the system should be changed, [ask a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) here.

Comment: Does my scenario about deleting and creating a new question satisfy the system?

Comment: @Zaph Yes it would.

Comment: But the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) also says "the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount."

Comment: That seems to be a complete paragraph and seems to address the issue at hand. It is one of several ways the bounty can be awarded. Well, after almost 50k of rep this was the first bounty I have been involved in and it was a sham, color me disappointed in the the system.